# Kibana connection failed to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed elasticsearch and logstash 1.4 off the Debian repository. It is working and collecting logs from another device forwarding syslog.

I followed the kibana install guide but I am getting an error message: Connection Failed
With check that es is running or ensure  that http.cors.enabled: true

In console I am getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://'127.0.0.1':9200/_nodes. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I have added this to my elasticsearch.yml:

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "http://192.168.1.1"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

That IP is the IP of itself since all 3 ELK apps run off the same host.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:::::

I got it working by adding Header set 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` right before the  tag in site-enabled. 
I also had to link to the module:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

Answer (score 0):

For these configs, you'll need to sudo or be root.

First, make sure you have the following lines in elasticsearch.yml (usually at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml):

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "http://192.168.1.1"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

(don't worry if the rest of the file is all commented out--the defaults should be fine)

The rest of the configs are for Apache, so go to the apache directory. For example:

```
cd /etc/apache2
```

In your enabled sites folder, add a "Header set" option. On a simple system, this may be in the file pointed to at /etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.conf. Inside the directive (perhaps after the line that sets DocumentRoot) add:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

For this to work, you also need to enable the headers module. Do:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ln -s ../mods-available/headers.load
```

Finally, don't forget to reload or restart the Apache server (reload if you can't stand a 1 second downtime). For example, on a sysvinit-style system:

```
service apache2 reload
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Then don't forget to refresh the page in your browser.